# Why is my program displaying "Exception in thread Thread-2"?

Tags: python, multithreading, sleep

I want to create a program to train myself to calculate squares of numbers between 11 and 99 in my head. I want to train to do this as quickly as possible. Therefore, to my first function I added a chronometer. I want to make them run at the same time, so when I have four good results, I can see how long it took me to do so. Here is my program:

```py
from random import randint
import threading
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def squares():
    i=0
    while i<4:
        x=randint(11,99)
        print (str(x))
        y=input()

        if int(y)==x*x:
            print('True')
            i=i+1
        else:
            print('False')
            print('Good answer: ',str(x*x))
        print (str(i),'/4')

def chrono():
    counter=0
    while i<4:
        sleep(1.)
        counter+=1
    print (counter)

Thread(target = squares).start()
Thread(target = chrono).start()
```

However, when I run it, it displays:

```
77Exception in thread Thread-2
```

Does someone have an explanation for that and could tell me how to fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire traceback. It will contain an explanation of why this happened.

Comment: i is not defined in function chrono